# Jquery deferred from callback of ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write an procedure that does something after 2 objects are returned as a result of the callback of an ajax function.

I know the classic example of using Jquery when():

```
$.when($.get("http://localhost:3000/url1"), 
$.get("http://localhost:3000/url2").done(//do something));
```

But in my case, I don't want to trigger the when on the execution of the ajax function, I want the when to trigger from the callback from the execution of the ajax function.  Something like:

```
$.get("http://localhost:3000/url1", function(data){
  function(){
    //do something with the data, and return myobj1;
  }
});

$.get("http://localhost:3000/url2", function(data){
  function(){
    //do something with the data, and return myobj2;
  }
});

$.when(obj1, obj2).done(function(){
  //do something with these 2 objects
});
```

But of course, that doesn't work.  Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That actually should work. [`jQuery.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) takes multiple arguments and fires once they all have completed returning each results arguments as an array:

```
var req1 = $.get("http://localhost:3000/url1");
var req2 = $.get("http://localhost:3000/url2");

$.when(req1, req2).done(function(res1, res2) {
    //do something with these 2 objects
});
```

If you don't want to handle the requests together you can create your own deferreds and use those:

```
var deferred1 = $.Deferred(),
    deferred2 = $.Deferred();

$.get("http://localhost:3000/url1", function(data){
    function(){
        //do something with the data, and return myobj1;
        deferred1.resolve(myobj1);
    }
});

$.get("http://localhost:3000/url2", function(data){
    function(){
        //do something with the data, and return myobj2;
        deferred2.resolve(myobj2);
    }
});

$.when(deferred1, deferred2).done(function(){
    //do something with these 2 objects
});
```

Comment: Yeah, what you posted works.  But the problem is that the when is initiated when the $.get functions come back, but if you notice above, I have callbacks happening for each of the $.get requests, and the when doesn't wait for these callbacks to process, just when the $.get functions finish.  So the when is firing too early.

Comment: @RyanOgle If you can't for some reason process the responses together, you can create your own deferreds and use those. Updated answers with the example.

Comment: @ Trevor I must be missing something here.  In your added example, is when() not supposed to trigger until the 2 deferreds get resolved?  I haven't gotten this to work.  Take a look at this simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/ax4u4/  when() is getting triggered even though the deferred objects are never resolved.

Comment: @RyanOgle You need to wrap `$(mydiv).css("background", "blue")` in a function and pass that as a callback. As is you are calling it immediately. Here is the fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ax4u4/1/

Comment: That seems weird to me that it executes expressions in .done() immediately, but not callbacks.  I would have thought that it would have at least just thrown an error (as it would expect a callback).  But that was the missing link, everything is working perfectly now.  Thanks very very much for the help.  You da man!

Comment: Also, looking at the code, it checks if the arguments passed for the done method is a 'function' or an 'array of functions'. If not, it seems to just ignore the arguments, hence no error. I wonder if having a error message here is useful or it wasn't added there by design? question for @JulianAubourg

Answer (score 0):

or you can do controls yourself

```
     $(function(){$('body').addClass('doc-ready')})
     var thingsToLoad = ['blabla.js','blublu.js','weee.js'];

     var launch = function(){

     // do whatever you want to do after loading is complete
     // this will be invoked after dom ready.
     // objectCollection will have everything you loaded.

     // and you can wrap your js files in functions, and execute whenever you want.

     }

     var loadTester = (function() {
        var loadCounter   = 0,
            loadEnds      = thingToLoad.length; // total number of items needs to be loaded
        return function() {
          loadCounter += 1;
          if (loadCounter === loadEnds) {
            if ($('body').hasClass('doc-ready')) {
              launch();
            } else {
              /* if body doesnt have ready class name, attach ready event and launch application */
              $(function() {
                launch();
              });
            }
          }
        }
      }());


$.each(thingsToLoad, function(i) {
    $.ajax({
      url      : thingsToLoad[i],
      mimeType : 'application/javascript',
      dataType : 'script',
      success  : function(data) {
        loadTester();
      }
    });
  });
```

add your files into `thingsToLoad` array,
at the end it will be iterated over and will be loaded after success, it will init
`loadTester`.

`loadTester` will check length of your `thingsToLoad` array, when number of loaded files vs files length matches and dom in ready status, it will `launch()`.

if you're just loading html files, or text files, you can pass those (`data` in ajax function) into `loadTester` and accumulate there (within a private var like those `loadCounter` and `loadEnds`), and pass accumulated array or object to `launch()`